# performance issue - if server is located in other country does affect speed?

Tags: performance, magento, country

we create a website in Europe, so it is hosted here,  but  it is an online shop (in magento)  that sell just in USA.

can the fact that is located in europe affect athe speed of the website, for US users?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the proximity of a server doesn't affect the connexion speed as such because you never know exactly the network road taken by your requests to get on the server. If speed is a concern though (and it should always be for an e-shop), you might want to optimize your code though, but that's a fairly large subject extensively covered on the web.

Comment: The loading speed of magento is not affected by that hosting country. Its depending on the server and the hosting services and finally configuration(code style, image etc) of your magento site..

Answer (score 0):

Ping distance from the server will affect the initial load time for new visitors, but should load faster once it has been cached by the user's client. Also be aware that Magento is a fairly hefty framework so will have higher loading times anyway

Answer (score 0):

It have minimal effect on load speed (waiting time) but on downloading speed yes, it can be visible.

You can use this tool it can show a time when the page is loaded from another destinations.

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

On a biggest projects is it ussualy solved by CDN services http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network